# How to deploy JAR file on JBoss?

Tags: java, spring, deployment, jboss, jar

I have a Java application using `Spring`, `Hibernate` and `JMX`.

Now i wanna deploy it on JBoss. I exported it to a Jar file and copy to the deploy folder of JBoss. But when i start JBoss, that app isn't deployed.

The error I saw that JBoss can't find out library files of Spring and Hibernate.So guys how to deploy a file Jar on JBoss ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289813/best-practice-for-loading-3rd-party-jars-in-jboss-as7-standalone-deployment

Comment: Not a duplication (of the quesiton linked at least), this one is about deploying jar containing the application, the other one is about packaging 3rd party jar.

Comment: Agree, not a duplicate. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2):

Java enterprise applications are not deployed as jar files, but as .war files (for web application) or .ear files (for complete enterprise applications, including EJB).

You would probably be looking at packaging your app as a .war file. Even if it's not a "web application", it needs to be packaged as one to be deployed to a Java enterprise/web container like JBOSS.

I would suggest browsing the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/) available from Oracle to learn more.

Comment: It's possible to deploy EJB-jar files directly in Jboss (jar extension), if they follow the EJB packaging model (you don't need to place it in an ear necessarily).

Comment: make JAR not WAR