# Deploying multiple wars for different modules but same portal

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts, maven-3, jboss7.x, ear

I have a legacy project which is struts based (1.2) and deployed on JBOSS AS 7.

The project started off small several years ago catering to one single product but now has several sections in it. We want to break them into maven modules and generate separate wars out of it and deploy them - so that whichever module needs changed will be re-released using the Jboss Management console.

Idea was to package all modules as self-sufficient wars in a EAR and deploy. However I see if I package all in an EAR there is no way one can hot-deploy a part of it i.e. a single war in it.
Is it even possible with an EAR?

Also all the module would have a common Login front end - Is there a way to a common Login-Only war which can then redirect to other wars while maintaining a session?

Comment: What do you mean by Login front end?  (You should create a different question for this).

Comment: Yes Kazaag. The 2nd one should be a different question. Will create another. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create expoided archive, so you can update war per war or any lib/*jar file idependently.

You should look [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/Application+deployment) to know how to trigger deployment of explodeded archive.

But this will be trigger as one app and the entire ear will be re-deployed each time you made a modification.  (There is no real hot deployed required by specs)

The other option is to put the depedency in different JBoss module ([example here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/09/jboss-modules-example-modular-web.html)) then you can have idependent wars with the shared jar in the modules.  But it will be complete different app, you won't be able to have shared EJBs or CDI bean between the different applications.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289813/best-practice-for-loading-3rd-party-jars-in-jboss-as7-standalone-deployment) have more details about module used to handle shared depedencies.

Comment: so basically if we deploy as an EAR with multiple wars in it - irrespective of whether I do a exploded deploy or a single EAR file - there is NO way on an App Server I can hot deploy only 1 of the wars as and when I need to?

Comment: I don't think you will be able to do so.

Comment: Thanks Kazaag. I will now create the other question in a separate thread